# Firebase-iOS storage error code -13000: Cannot finalise upload

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload images to the new firebase storage service. For some reason, it throws an error the first time I upload and it works fine when I try selecting the same image to upload.

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
let fileName = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString + ".jpg"
let uploadRef = storageRef.child("\(bucketName)/\(fileName)")
let uploadTask = uploadRef.putFile(imageURL, metadata: nil)
```

The error that is thrown:

> Error
>  
>   Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain 
>  
>   Code=-13000 
>  
>   "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response."
>  
>   UserInfo={object=display-picture/DCCE1A99-BD0F-44F9-B1FA-7BF8F8209C43-7132-0000088406C78BC3.jpg,
>  
>   bucket=project-**************.appspot.com, 
>  
>   ResponseBody=Can not
>   finalize upload.  Current size is 92596.  Expected final size is
>   58228., 
>  
>   data=<43616e20 6e6f7420 66696e61 6c697a65 2075706c 6f61642e 20204375 7272656e 74207369 7a652069 73203932 3539362e 20204578
>   70656374 65642066 696e616c 2073697a 65206973 20353832 32382e>,
>  
>   NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the
>   server response., 
>  
>   ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus,
>   ResponseErrorCode=400}

Comment: That's a pretty strange error :(

Looks like for some reason, it uploaded the file incorrectly the first time. You're saying that it works on all subsequent requests though, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, only if the same request is repeated again. If I try a different request, it fails with the same error, but works again when repeated. It looks to me like creating a file is an issue, but once a reference is created, it overwrites normally.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a question asked a long time ago but this could help others in the future.

I had this problem as well and I was able to fix it by putting the upload logic on the main thread like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    uploadTask = uploadRef.putFile(imageURL, metadata: nil)
}
```

I found that solution on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1888#issuecomment-431545540)